# While loop only finding the last iteration

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, while-loop, fetch

So for school i am trying to build a webshop (it's a project) and for the cart i use a database where i get the information based upon the user and print that. HOWEVER my while loop only finds the last item and not the other two. Now i am pretty sure that the old data is being overwritten so that it won't be printed, but i don't know how to fix this

this is what i got so far:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ismsite', 'root', 'e-scooter');
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart where user_id=:userid ORDER BY cart_id DESC LIMIT 3 ");
    $result->bindParam(':userid', $_SESSION['userid']);
    $result->execute();
    $info = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $pid = $row['product_id'];
        $quantity = $row['quantity'];

        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE productID=:pid");
        $result->bindParam(':pid', $pid);
        $result->execute();

        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo $row['naam'];
        }

    }
}
else{

    echo "Je moet inloggen om te kunnen winkelen.";

}
?>
```

Can anyone help me out on this one?

Comment: You're using `$row` and `$result` for both loops, so the values from the inner loop override those from the outer loop..... bound to cause problems.... if you have to nest loops like this, use different variable names for each (at least for `$result`)

Comment: If you learned to use SQL JOINs, then you wouldn't even need to nest your loops

Comment: i don't know sql joins, it's just the second semester of the first year for me

Comment: But you could do some reading / learning on your own, right?

Comment: Try using this query instead of your main one. Remove the second query and the second while loop. `echo $row['naam']` and see what results you get
`SELECT c.*, p.* FROM cart c INNER JOIN Products p ON p.product_id = c.product_id where user_id=:userid ORDER BY cart_id DESC LIMIT 3`

I am assuming that product_id is a field in both tables.

Comment: i think it's happen coz overwrite a variable like $result,$row plz check my ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [SQL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Try this way:-

```
 $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ismsite', 'root', 'e-scooter');
             $sql = "SELECT cart.*,Products.* FROM cart 
                    LEFT JOIN Products
                    ON cart.product_id = Products.productID
                    where cart.user_id=:userid ORDER BY cart.cart_id DESC LIMIT 3"; 
                $result = $db->prepare($sql);
                $result->bindParam(':userid', $_SESSION['userid']);
                $result->execute();                   

                while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                   echo $row['naam'];
                }
```

Comment: This still only prints the last item

Answer (score 2):

Your code overwrite a variable like `$result,$row`.In inner loop you overwrite a $row and $result So your outer While loop not work well.

```
     while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                                    $pid = $row['product_id'];
                                    $quantity = $row['quantity'];

                                    $result1 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE productID=:pid");
                                    $result1->bindParam(':pid', $pid);
                                    $result1->execute();

                                    while($row1 = $result1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                                        echo $row1['naam'];
                                    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a conflict with your varible names.
Try this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ismsite', 'root', 'e-scooter');
    $cart = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart where user_id=:userid ORDER BY cart_id DESC LIMIT 3 ");
    $cart->bindParam(':userid', $_SESSION['userid']);
    $cart->execute();
    $info = array();

    while($row = $cart->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $pid = $row['product_id'];
        $quantity = $row['quantity'];
        $products = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE productID=:pid");
        $products->bindParam(':pid', $pid);
        $products->execute();

        while($product = $products->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
              echo $product['naam'];
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a for loop instead of a while loop

```
for($i = 0, $c = count($result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); $i < $c; $i++){
    //Do stuff here
}
```